# Show paragraph marks, spaces and other formatting marks in a contenteditable div

Tags: html, css

I need to show paragraph marks, spaces and other formatting marks in a contenteditable div as you can in MS Word by pressing the Formatting Marks button [Formatting Marks button http://blogs.mccombs.utexas.edu/the-most/files/2011/04/show-hide-button-in-outlook.jpg](http://blogs.mccombs.utexas.edu/the-most/files/2011/04/show-hide-button-in-outlook.jpg)

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: google wysiwyg editors... you will find plenty of them free to use.

Comment: reference - http://remysharp.com/2010/06/03/signs-of-a-poorly-written-jquery-plugin/ similar sort of effect when you hover over headings may be useful

Comment: I'm familiar with wysiwyg editors such as TinyMCE and CKEditor but as far as I'm aware they don't have the feature I'm looking for, i.e. showing spaces as dots and carriage returns as paragraph marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a font which draws spaces as dots and newlines as paragraph marks should solve your problem.

In code it will look like

```
.editable-div {
    font-family: "Your custom font with spaces as dots and stuff", "Actual character font";
}
```

Here's an article which elaborates on this approach http://www.sitepoint.com/joy-of-subsets-web-fonts/

Comment: Can you give an example of such a font?

Comment: Sorry, don't have such. You can draw one here for example http://www.glyphrstudio.com/online/, and copy the actual shapes from some Arial or    an open source font. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   span::after{
    color:black;
    content:"\00b6";
}
          p::after{
    color:black;
    content:"\00b6";
}
          
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h3>
   <span class="label">This is the main label</span>
   <span class="secondary-label">secondary label</span>
  </h3>
  <P>Quote me</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

*(I don't have access to Word, but I'm assuming it's the exact same functionality present in most text editors, or InDesign's 'show hidden characters' option &c.)*

No, there definitely isn't a simple way to do this, because it's a fairly complex feature.

Your best bet if you *really* want to do this is to capture the input within the div as a user enters text. Something like [Bacon](http://baconjs.github.io/) that can easily capture keyed user input as a stream (and allow you to map across the stream) would simplify the process somewhat.

You'll then need to replace* (in realtime) every space/paragraph mark/&c with a relevant marker *for the user*. The *actual* input still needs be either saved as typed, or parsed again before saving to strip the new, pretend characters. And though you can use use unicode entities for many of the markers (pilcrows, maybe?), a space (for example) will still show as whitespace (or as the entity code if escaped), so you would need to use a representative icon - essentially, the majority of the hidden characters will each need to have their own specific, defined rendering rules.

This is all fairly nightmarish. It's doable if you can ensure the max amount of text can be kept small, and if you can control what users can enter. For large amounts of text, I can see it becoming horrific: not sure what the JS overhead would be in terms of performance, but I can't imagine it would be particularly good.

---

* or append - for example newlines/carriage returns etc need to be both displayed as a marker, and actually occur within the contenteditable element.

---

**Edit**: What you could do in addition to the above is to edit a font, replacing/adding unicode points for hidden characters instead/as well as visible ones - you would still need to capture input, but this would remove a few headaches. It would deal with spaces quite nicely, for example. Still a bit of a nightmare, but hey.