# Display Soft Hyphen In HTML textArea

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I'm running into an issue where users of a site are copying and pasting characters into a textArea in an input form. Occasionally, they'll inadvertently paste in a soft hyphen (&shy), but it's not displayed in the pasted text. I know that I could remove the soft hyphen from the strings, but is there a way to ensure that all characters, including the soft hyphen (or other "invisible" characters?), are displayed in the text area?

Comment: provide simple code that we can use to test. MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I guess using a custom font [as suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25156048/5695459) should work.

Comment: BTW, textarea is intended for plain text. If you need to display invisible characters, you might want to consider using a [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-contenteditable) div instead.